# How to explicitly get linear indices from arrayfire?

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, matrix-indexing, arrayfire

Suppose I have an `stl::array<float, 24> foo` which is the linearized STL pendant to a Column-Major format arrayfire array, e.g. `af::array bar = af::array(4,3,2, 1, f32);`. So I have an `af::dim4` object `dims` with the dimensions of `bar`, I have up to 4 `af::seq`-objects and I have the linearized array `foo`.

How is it possible to get explicitly the indices of `foo` (i.e. linearized version of `bar`) representing e.g. the 2.nd and 3.rd row, i.e. `bar(af::seq(1,2), af::span, af::span, af::span)`? I have a small code example given below, which shows what I want. In the end I also explain why I want this.

```
af::dim4 bigDims = af::dim4(4,3,2);
stl::array<float, 24> foo;   // Resides in RAM and is big
float* selBuffer_ptr;        // Necessary for AF correct type autodetection
stl::vector<float> selBuffer;
// Load some data into foo
af::array selection;         // Resides in VRAM and is small

af::seq selRows = af::seq(1,2);
af::seq selCols = af::seq(bigDims[1]);   // Emulates af::span
af::seq selSlices = af::seq(bigDims[2]); // Emulates af::span
af::dim4 selDims = af::dim4(selRows.size, selCols.size, selSlices.size);    

dim_t* linIndices;
// Magic functionality getting linear indices of the selection
//  selRows x selCols x selSlices

// Assign all indexed elements to a consecutive memory region in selBuffer
// I know their positions within the full dataset, b/c I know the selection ranges.

selBuffer_ptr = static_cast<float> &(selBuffer[0]);

selection = af::array(selDims, selBuffer_ptr);      // Copies just the selection to the device (e.g. GPU)

// Do sth. with selection and be happy
// I don't need to write back into the foo array.
```

Arrayfire must have such a logic implemented in order to access elements and I found several related classes/functions such as `af::index, af::seqToDims, af::gen_indexing, af::array::operator()` - however I couldn't figure an easy way out yet.

I thought about basically reimplementing the `operator()`, so that it would work similarly but not require a reference to an array-object. But this might be wasted effort if there is an easy way in the arrayfire-framework.

**Background:**
The reason I want to do so is because arrayfire does not allow to store data only in main memory (CPU-context) while being linked against a GPU backend. Since I have a big chunk of data that needs to be processed only piece by piece and the VRAM is quite limited, I'd like to instantiate `af::array`-objects ad-hoc from an stl-container which always resided in main memory.

Of course I know that I could program some index magic to work around my problem but I'd like to use quite complicated `af::seq` objects which could make an efficient implementation of the index logic complicated.

Comment: Why would linear indices help in this case ? If you can show some code about what you plan to do after you get linear indices that'd be great.

Answer (score 1):

After a discussion with Pavan Yalamanchili on Gitter I managed to get a working piece of code that I want to share in case anybody else needs to hold his variables only in RAM and copy-on-use parts of it to VRAM, i.e. the Arrayfire universe (if linked against OpenCL on GPU or Nvidia).

This solution will also help anybody who is using AF somewhere else in his project anyways and who wants to have a convenient way of accessing a big linearized N-dim array with (N<=4).

```
//  Compile as: g++ -lafopencl malloc2.cpp && ./a.out
#include <stdio.h>
#include <arrayfire.h>
#include <af/util.h>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

#define M 3
#define N 12
#define O 2
#define SIZE M*N*O


int main() {
    int _foo;                      // Dummy variable for pausing program
    double* a = new double[SIZE];  // Allocate double array on CPU (Big Dataset!)
    for(long i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) // Fill with entry numbers for easy debugging
        a[i] = 1. * i + 1;

    std::cin >> _foo; // Pause 

    std::cout << "Full array: ";
    // Display full array, out of convenience from GPU
    // Don't use this if "a" is really big, otherwise you'll still copy all the data to the VRAM.
    af::array ar = af::array(M, N, O, a);   // Copy a RAM -> VRAM


    af_print(ar);

    std::cin >> _foo; // Pause 


    // Select a subset of the full array in terms of af::seq
    af::seq seq0 = af::seq(1,2,1);     // Row 2-3
    af::seq seq1 = af::seq(2,6,2);     // Col 3:5:7
    af::seq seq2 = af::seq(1,1,1);     // Slice 2


    // BEGIN -- Getting linear indices
    af::array aidx0 = af::array(seq0);
    af::array aidx1 = af::array(seq1).T() * M;
    af::array aidx2 = af::reorder(af::array(seq2), 1, 2, 0) * M * N;

    af::gforSet(true);
    af::array aglobal_idx = aidx0 + aidx1 + aidx2;
    af::gforSet(false);

    aglobal_idx = af::flat(aglobal_idx).as(u64);
    // END -- Getting linear indices

    // Copy index list VRAM -> RAM (for easier/faster access)
    uintl* global_idx = new uintl[aglobal_idx.dims(0)];
    aglobal_idx.host(global_idx);

    // Copy all indices into a new RAM array
    double* a_sub = new double[aglobal_idx.dims(0)];
    for(long i = 0; i < aglobal_idx.dims(0); i++)
        a_sub[i] = a[global_idx[i]];

    // Generate the "subset" array on GPU & diplay nicely formatted
    af::array ar_sub = af::array(seq0.size, seq1.size, seq2.size, a_sub);
    std::cout << "Subset array: ";  // living on seq0 x seq1 x seq2
    af_print(ar_sub);

    return 0;
}

/*
g++ -lafopencl malloc2.cpp && ./a.out 

Full array: ar
[3 12 2 1]
    1.0000     4.0000     7.0000    10.0000    13.0000    16.0000    19.0000    22.0000    25.0000    28.0000    31.0000    34.0000 
    2.0000     5.0000     8.0000    11.0000    14.0000    17.0000    20.0000    23.0000    26.0000    29.0000    32.0000    35.0000 
    3.0000     6.0000     9.0000    12.0000    15.0000    18.0000    21.0000    24.0000    27.0000    30.0000    33.0000    36.0000 

   37.0000    40.0000    43.0000    46.0000    49.0000    52.0000    55.0000    58.0000    61.0000    64.0000    67.0000    70.0000 
   38.0000    41.0000    44.0000    47.0000    50.0000    53.0000    56.0000    59.0000    62.0000    65.0000    68.0000    71.0000 
   39.0000    42.0000    45.0000    48.0000    51.0000    54.0000    57.0000    60.0000    63.0000    66.0000    69.0000    72.0000 

ar_sub
[2 3 1 1]
   44.0000    50.0000    56.0000 
   45.0000    51.0000    57.0000 
*/
```

The solution uses some undocumented AF functions and is supposedly slow due to the for loop running over global_idx, but so far its really the best one can do if on wants to hold data in the CPU context exclusively and share only parts with the GPU context of AF for processing.

If anybody knows a way to speed this code up, I'm still open for suggestions.